How to draw 3D graphics using Winform technology (. NET Framework 4.8) in C # library development
I now have a Python file that can draw the 3D image I want. I want to convert it into C # code, but it seems that C# library development cannot directly draw 3D images. What should I do?
I have tried using the external extension Scottplot, but it was not successful.

Your question is a bit too vague for SO. SO requires questions to be more specific than this. There are other places that broader questions like this one are OK. You probably want a forum rather than a Q&A site. Definitely continue to use SO when you do have more specific questions, but this one is not appropriate as it it.

C # library development cannot directly draw 3D images - C# has full access to Direct3D and OpenGL, so your assumption is incorrect. That information should give you enough to do some searching with your favorite search engine.

The simplest option is to host a wpf 3D view in your winforms window. This is fairly simple and easy to use, and is hardware accelerated, so should give fairly good performance.  You might also want to take a look at Helix toolkit for some improvements on the basic wpf controls.
Other options include a direct X wrapper like sharpDX or SlimDX, but neither is maintained. You could also access DirectX directly, but you probably need to be fairly familiar with COM or C / C++.
OpenGL or a wrapper like OpenTK could also be an option. But both DirectX and OpenGL are fairly low level, and will require some knowledge about the rendering pipeline, as well as how to integrate the rendered image into your window.
There might also be third party libraries. If that is what you are after see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
For very simple 3D graphics you could just do all the 3D math yourself in software and just draw triangles.

You might want to try to integrate Python script with .NET library. You can use IronPython or Python.NET to do so.
